# Why is the grid showing 4hrs before than the time it has in the database

Tags: c#, .net, acumatica, erp, acumatica-kb

I have a problem showing the Date and Time on a Grid on Acumatica. it is supposed to show the exact same time it has on the database but instead is showing 4 hours before like its a TimeZone issue.

My code is like this:

DAC definition

```
#region TodaysDate
public abstract class todaysDate : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}

[PXDBDateAndTime(UseTimeZone = false, PreserveTime = true, DisplayNameDate = "Date", DisplayNameTime = "Time")]
[PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
public virtual DateTime? TodaysDate { get; set; }
#endregion
```

Aspx definition

```
<px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100" 
    Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Details" TabIndex="4200">
    <Levels>
        <px:PXGridLevel DataKeyNames="OrderType,OrderNbr,TodaysDate" DataMember="TruckCheckRecord">
            <RowTemplate>
                <px:PXDateTimeEdit ID="edTodaysDate" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="TodaysDate" IsClientControl="True" InputMask="hh:mm">
                </px:PXDateTimeEdit>
            </RowTemplate>
            <Columns>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="OrderType">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="OrderNbr">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="BAccount__AcctName" Width="120px">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Trucker" Width="120px">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Contno" Width="120px">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Seal" Width="120px">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Outside">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Inside">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Opening">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Temp">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Pests">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Pesticides">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Documents">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Employee" Width="120px">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="TodaysDate" Width="102px" DisplayFormat="g">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
            </Columns>
        </px:PXGridLevel>
    </Levels>
    <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
</px:PXGrid>
```

I've tried variations on the DAC to see if that solves the problem but it always shows the result as the following

Values shown in gridview:

[image]

Database values for the same records

[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Brendan's answer says to use PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.Now but where do I use it? @Orace

Comment: because my problem is not when the record is saving, my issue is just to show the data on a grid showed by an inquiry page

Comment: check your login if its explicitly set to a specific timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Check the timezone (under User Profile -> General Info -> Personal Settings) of the current login user. For the better visibility to the user, UI displays the datetime based on the user's selected timezone and not the exact values in the database.